# When is it appropriate to use \paragraph?

Tags: sectioning, best-practices, sections-paragraphs

LaTeX provides seven sectioning commands:

1. `\part`
2. `\chapter`
3. `\section`
4. `\subsection`
5. `\subsubsection`
6. `\paragraph`
7. `\subparagraph`.

For most of the documents I write or come across, `\subsubsection` seems to be the deepest sectioning level used. Then there's the "rule" (by Tufte perhaps? I am unable to find the source right now) that suggests that the document outline should not be deeper than three levels, which would leave me somewhere between `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` depending on the document class being used. At any rate, I have not yet come across a use case for `\paragraph` and, thinking about it, I realize I don't know when it would be appropriate to use it. So, that's my question: when, if ever, should `\paragraph` be used?

Comment: I used `\paragraph` once in a proposal, but only because I could "safely" redefine it.

Comment: Maybe in very technical or legal documents, where everything has to be very clearly structured.

Comment: at least some legal documents use sectioning levels as deep as `\paragraph` and possibly (much) deeper.

Comment: `\paragraph` is also a quick and dirty inline section which I sometimes use for small documents where space is at a premium, like one page abstracts for conferences, where some structure is needed, but you don't need to number everything.

Comment: Typesetting Wittgenstein's works?  And more seriously: in standard LaTeX classes, `\paragraph` is "less visible" than some `\sub...section`s, so might be useful (especially in its unnumbered version).

Comment: I used it in my dissertation but that might be taken as a dis-recommendation. Some standard works use numbered paragraphs so that readers can find references even if the pagination of their edition differs. (There are other systems which enable this, too, but paragraphing is certainly one option.)

Comment: @cfr I would argue that works with numbered paragraphs (e.g. *The Chicago Manual of Style*) have nothing to do with `\paragraph`. The latter is simply another sectioning level and could have been called `\subsubsubsection` or `\foo` as well. For example, you have a single reference per "typeset paragraph" in the *CmoS*, when you can insert as many typeset paragraphs as you want within a `\paragraph` section. `\paragraph` should thus not be confused with typeset paragraphs.

Comment: @ebo Possibly. But these are being used for referencing purposes, so they are more section-division-like. That is, you're effectively turning each typeset paragraph into a division of the document which can be referenced.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I learned in elementary school that a document should not be divided more than the intellectual content deserves. The rule is often breached, especially by lawyers. One reason for numbering down to eight or nine levels is that it is easy for us lawyers to refer to item 2.1.1.2.3.(i)(b)(V)(A) in a complicated legal text, making the text even harder to read and interpret. Then we lawyers are sure you have to visit a lawyer and pay him to help you with the interpretation.

Bringhurst (*The Elements of Typographic Style*) suggests three levels.

(And: I am a lawyer myself)

Comment: +1 for the deep insight into the wonders of the legal world. French lawyers are even better: they insist on having only two parts, two chapters per part, etc. Then we need at least 11 or 12 levels, and an army of lawyers.

Comment: Thank you for the Bringhurst reference. Legal documents were the only ones that came to mind when I asked this question, but I did not want to bias the answers. Now I know!

Comment: Usually, \paragraph does not introduce numbering, and thus does not actually act as a sectioning command. I use it mainly for emphasis of or as a minor header for a paragraph. It usually looks the same as a simple \textbf{}, but is much more obvious what is meant.

Comment: First time I heard IAALM instead of IANAL...

Comment: Bringhurst does _not_ suggests three levels. Section 4.2.2 of The Elements of Typographic Style version 3.2 states _Use as many levels of headings as you need: no more and no fewer._

Comment: @neic But, as far as I remember, he also (somewhere) says something about three levels. I will find the reference, when I have time (I have his book in my office). And I say the same, use as many levels as the intellectual content deserves, and for most of us, three levels probably are more than enough.

Answer (score 41):

There is no real need for that many subdivisions unless (perhaps) you are writing a twenty-volume comprehensive book and you use continuous numbering of sections.

While Bringhurst's three levels may be too little for the average academic book (i.e., 300 to 600 pages, with very structured content unlike in literature), you won't see many that have over five levels of headings either. Five levels means `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section` `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`, and that's the most you will usually find.

But I would like to suggest that `\paragraph` and friends can be used a bit differently from `\section` commands, from a semantic point of view. It is common practice to define paragraphs as inline headings, and to hide them from the table of content. Say you wanted a book with two main headings (`\chapter` and `\section`) and a third heading that creates a small break in the text but doesn't use a full line, then `\paragraph` would be appropriate.

What I really mean is that the headings are not there for you to use each and every one of them as if they formed a rigid hierarchy, but because they have different meanings. A `\chapter` starts a new page, a `\section` does not and a `\paragraph` has yet another style. You don't have to exhaust `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` before jumping to `\paragraph` – the `\sub…` are always pretty much optional. It is better to use them in a semantic way.

Unless you are a lawyer of course, as mentioned by Sveinung.

Answer (score 14):

Funny as I found Sveinung's answer, I can't resist leaping to the defence of my profession (and without payment!).

It's a mistake to see these divisions as forming a continuous sequence. Division into, say, parts and chapters is really discontinuous with division into sections and so forth within a chapter.  Paragraph headings, as ienissei points out serve a different purpose again. In a long text that will be consulted rather than read continuously they help one to scan for the relevant part. That I think gives a good guide to when they are appropriate: in works of reference, mostly intended for an audience that will probably be reading fast with a particular objective, and which will have a general idea already about the sort of information the text will contain. Reference manuals for professionals, basically.

The endless subdivisions of lawyers in formal texts are different again: they don't structure the document, but split up individual paragraphs and sentences of often very dense material in a way that helps clarify it and facilitates cross references. This sequence is again separate from and discontinuous with the headings and subheadings which are about the structure of the document.

Believe it or not, they actually help, though like headings they can be overdone. Anyone who has struggled through an old legal document in which there is no punctuation because it was believed that said punctuation might rather than assisting the reader lead to misinterpretation of the text and accordingly to misapplication of the same will be likely to appreciate the advantages of the modern style its inelegance notwithstanding. !